# How to respond to a javascript alert message in QWebView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qwebview

How can I detect that a java alert message has raised in `QWebView` object and how to bypass it or click "leave this page"?

An example on the message is the facebook message that appears when I add post to group and trying to leave group without posting it, something like this image:
[image]